# ArcGIS 10.1 Aggregate Points cannot create output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, in-memory, error-000210

I'm trying to use the tool Aggregate Points with output created using in_memory but the tool keeps failing with: "ERROR 000210 Cannot create output \Output_Tbl"

The tool works fine if I use a GDB feature class as output. Does anyone know how to use output for in_memory with this tool?
[image]

Comment: I am able to replicate this, getting the same error message on 10.2.1. Able to write to a disk into a file geodatabase and scratch geodatabase (tested from both Python script and GUI).

Comment: Looks like a bug maybe you should report it to esri?

Comment: I have observed that areas and lengths are not calculated when using in_memory workspaces, and Aggregate Points gets given a length parameter.  Also there are other reports like http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17718-in_memory-workspace-doesn-t-work-with-many-ArcGIS-10-tools.  I strongly recommend that you report this one which sounds like it is easy to reproduce, and then to post an NIM "bug" number here as part of a self-Answer.  I say "bug" because it may be an undocumented software limitation.

Comment: It's not *in memory*, the Aggregate points needs to create a temporary table and it looks like it's not setup for INFO table. Try to create an ArcINFO workspace and run it there. Yes, this is a bug, but knowing the limitations you can work within them to produce the intended output... what's wrong with running this in a file/personal geodatabase?

Comment: I have contacted my Esri International Distributor and they will look into the problem and report it if it is a bug. @Michael, I only needed the output temporary inside a script and I feel that in_memory is often faster than local GDB so that is why I would prefer to use in_memory over GDB

Answer (score 1):

ESRI looked at the problem and have now logged it as bug NIM102306

Comment: Are you able to edit into your problem the brief description that they associated with that NIM number?

Comment: No unfortunately I don't have any options to edit the bug description. It is only ESRI who can do that. But yes it is a bit weak description they have written for this bug.